# Automate generating deploy key for github

Tags: bash, github, ssh-keys

I execute the following commands a few times a day:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -C "info@example.com" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_projectname
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_projectname
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_projectname.pub
ssh -T git@github.com
```

The only variable in this script is the `projectname`, I would like to make a `keygen.sh` script or something like that to automate this process and pass along the `projectname`. Is this possible?

Also where should I start looking and what not to forget, I'm a bit new to bash scripting and I know it can be quite dangerous in the wrong hands.

Comment: You generate deploy keys multiple times every day? Why?

Comment: @Chris two or three times a day when i clone a new repo from Github to a new staging or developer enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it not be easier to just maintain a single set of staging or development keys rather than generating them for everything? IMHO you're losing configurability and not gaining much in security.

That aside, you're on the right track but I would do things a bit different.

```
export PROJECT=foo;
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -C "info@example.com" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_${PROJECT}
```

That will generate named keys id_rsa_foo and id_rsa_foo.pub
Now you need to make your ssh config use it for github. `~/.ssh/config` should have something like:

```
Host            remote github.com
IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa_foo
User            git
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

You'll need to upload the public key to github. You'll have to figure this out for yourself using their API.

If you do all this correctly you should be able to git clone automagically.

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -z "${PROJECT}" ]] && echo "project must be set" && exit 1
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -C "info@example.com" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_${PROJECT}
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa_${PROJECT}
echo $'     Host            remote github.com\n    IdentityFile     ~/.ssh/id_rsa_'${PROJECT}'\n    User            git\n      StrictHostKeyChecking no' >> ~/.ssh/config
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config
# do the github api stuff to add the pub key
```